# iOS Auto Layout keeps the minimum gap when the space is not enough, and takes up as much space as possible when the space is enough

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, masonry, snapkit

[image]

This is the layout. The top Label text may get very long, and I expect the Label selected at the bottom to be at least 40 pt from the bottom button when there is enough space at the moment, and at least 10 pt when there is not enough space.I tried prioritizing but it doesn't seem to work, please help me. Here is part of my code.

```
buttonView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
  make.leading.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
  make.height.equalTo(buttonView.intrinsicContentSize.height)
}

contentLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
  make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(headerImageView.snp.bottom).offset(10.dp)
  make.leading.equalTo(50.dph)
  make.trailing.equalTo(-50.dph)
}

codeTextField.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
  make.top.equalTo(contentLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10.dp)
  make.leading.equalTo(46.5.dp)
  make.trailing.equalTo(-46.5.dp)
  make.height.equalTo(50.dp)
}

tipsLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
  make.top.equalTo(codeTextField.snp.bottom).offset(10.dp)
  make.width.centerX.equalTo(codeTextField)
  make.bottom.equalTo(buttonView.snp.top).offset(-10.dp)
  make.bottom.greaterThanOrEqualTo(buttonView.snp.top).offset(-40.dp)
}
```

[Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VK4l-aggH1Ra8C8uA6pdkjOe4hx_ntR2/view?usp=sharing) to download the demo project.

Comment: when the text long, is your Label Top change ?

Comment: Hi @goat_herd No, the Label is always at 10 pt below the TextField.

Comment: @VincentSit - I grabbed the demo project you linked to... is this your goal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIz3b.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBbUp.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDPxF.png

Comment: @DonMag Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things...

First, you want to set Compression Resistance on your "tips" label so it doesn't get squeezed out of existence.

Second, when you give an object constraints such as:

```
bottom of viewA greaterThanOrEqual to -40 from top of viewB
bottom of viewA lessThanOrEqual to -10 from top of viewB
```

you have not given a complete layout. ***ANY*** value between -40 and -10 would be valid, so auto-layout doesn't understand what you really want.

To fix that, based on your descriptions, you want 40-pts *if possible*, and *at least* 10-pts. So you want two constraints that say:

- bottom of viewA `at least` -10 from top of viewB
- bottom of viewA `equalTo` -40 from top of viewB - ***unless there is not enough space*** - so give it a `Priority` less than `required`

Try this code - I added `// MARK: DonMag ...` comments where I made changes:

```
class MyView: UIView {

  override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool { return true }

    // MARK: DonMag - a few varied length contentLabel strings
    private var idx: Int = 0
    private let examples: [String] = [
        "Check your email.",
        "Please check your email to activate your account.\n\nEnter the activation code:",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    ]

  private let headerView = UIButton().then {
    $0.backgroundColor = .purple
    $0.setTitle("Tap me!", for: .normal)
  }

  private let contentLabel = UILabel().then {
    $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 21)
    $0.numberOfLines = 0
    $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    
    // MARK: DonMag - so we can see its frame
    $0.textAlignment = .center
    $0.backgroundColor = .cyan

  }

  private let codeTextField = UITextField().then {
    $0.placeholder = "Enter code"
    $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    $0.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
    $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    $0.textAlignment = .center
    $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 21)
    $0.keyboardType = .numberPad
  }

  private let tipsLabel = UILabel().then {
    $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    $0.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    $0.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
    $0.textAlignment = .center
    $0.text = "If you have not received the code, tap 'resend'."
    $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    
    // MARK: DonMag - prevent label from being compressed vertically
    $0.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    // MARK: DonMag - so we can see its frame
    $0.backgroundColor = .yellow

  }

  private let bottomView = UIView().then {
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .white

    addSubview(headerView)
    addSubview(contentLabel)
    addSubview(codeTextField)
    addSubview(tipsLabel)
    addSubview(bottomView)

    headerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(headerViewDidTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    headerViewDidTapped()
  }

  override func updateConstraints() {
    headerView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
      make.leading.trailing.top.equalToSuperview()
      make.height.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.454)
    }

    bottomView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
      make.leading.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
      make.height.equalTo(121)
    }

    contentLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
      make.leading.equalTo(50)
      make.trailing.equalTo(-50)
    }

    codeTextField.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.equalTo(contentLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
      make.leading.equalTo(46.5)
      make.trailing.equalTo(-46.5)
      make.height.equalTo(50)
    }

    tipsLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.equalTo(codeTextField.snp.bottom).offset(10)
      make.width.centerX.equalTo(codeTextField)
      make.bottom.greaterThanOrEqualTo(bottomView.snp.top).offset(-40)
        
      // MARK: DonMag - tipsLabel bottom should be equalTo -40 with medium priority (so it can be overridden by auto-layout when needed)
      //make.bottom.greaterThanOrEqualTo(bottomView.snp.top).offset(-40)
      make.bottom.equalTo(bottomView.snp.top).offset(-40).priority(.medium)
        
      make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(bottomView.snp.top).offset(-10)
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  @objc
  private func headerViewDidTapped() {

    // MARK: DonMag - get example string for contentLabel
    let text = examples[idx % examples.count]
    idx += 1

    contentLabel.text = text
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make two constraint:

```
make.bottom.greaterThanOrEqualTo(buttonView.snp.top).offset(-40)
make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(buttonView.snp.top).offset(-10)
make.height.equalTo(21)
```

And change priority of your content label constraint:

```
      make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(10).priority(751)
```

Comment: Hi @goat_herd, thanks for the answer, I tried it, and it doesn't seem to work, just like the screenshot. Currently there is enough space, but the Label is 10 pt from the bottom instead of 40 pt. I'm writing a demo, I can provide a project for debugging later.

Comment: can you change this constraint from greaterThanOrEqual to equal : make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(headerImageView.snp.bottom).offset(10.dp). Is there any problem

Comment: Hi @goat_herd, It's not working either. Here the demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VK4l-aggH1Ra8C8uA6pdkjOe4hx_ntR2/view?usp=sharing